# how to index measurements with spatial coordinates

Tags: python, spatial-index, rtree

I am beginner with the RTree I use libspatialindex, I will want to know how I insert a polygon / point with a measurement (statistic or measurement of weather)
do I have to change the structure ?

```
from rtree import index

idx = index.Index()
idx.insert(0, (0, 0, 1,1 ),my mesure)
```

yet I see in the class Node the attribute byte** m_pData; (it is he who contains the information of each leaf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're reading the [libspatialite documentation](http://libspatialindex.github.io/doxygen/). Libspatialite is written in C++.

Your code uses RTree. This is a Python library, which uses Libspatialite.

See [using rtree as a cheapo spatial database](http://toblerity.org/rtree/tutorial.html#using-rtree-as-a-cheapo-spatial-database).

Anything which can be '[pickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)' can be used as the last parameter.

For example, you could pass a simple value

```
index.insert(id=id, bounds=(left, bottom, right, top), obj=42)
```

or something more detailed...

```
index.insert(id=id, bounds=(left, bottom, right, top), obj={'average':42,'count':12,'type':'awesome'})
```

RTree will take your python objects and convert them into the objects needed by Libspatialite.